# expository articles on special values of L functions

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

While searching for some notes on L functions i have seen the following statement...

In mathematics, the study of **special values of L-functions** is a sub field of number theory devoted to generalizing formulae such as the Leibniz formula for pi, namely

$$1 \,-\, \frac{1}{3} \,+\, \frac{1}{5} \,-\, \frac{1}{7} \,+\, \frac{1}{9} \,-\, \cdots \;=\; \frac{\pi}{4}$$

by the recognition that expression on the left-hand side is also $L(1)$ where $L(s)$ is the Dirichlet L-function for the Gaussian field.

Please suggest some basic references and links of some expository articles on these special values of L functions..

Comment: You aren't really going to care much about special values of L-functions until you know a bit about the importance of L-functions. Which ones have you studied?

Comment: @fretty I  have not studied many L functions... Only L function i know is  Dirichlet  L function..

Comment: Well there are formulae for special values of those as well as the Riemann zeta function. However "special values of L-functions" is a bit of a misnomer...it is not so much about just calculating values but relating these values to number theoretic phenomena. For example the one you cite above has information hidden in it about the Gaussian field $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and its ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (for example unique factorisation).

Answer (score 3):

The modern theory is both very deep and very broad, so there won't be a truly elementary introduction that gives you a feel for all of its dimensions.  For example, two huge conjectures about special values of L-functions are

1) The Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer

2) The Stark conjectures

(The first, being a millenium prize problem, is discussed by Keith Devlin in his book "The Millenium Prize Problems")  Getting a solid understanding of even these topics requires a very large amount of background.  And both of these are subsumed by the equivariant Tamagawa number conjecture, which is understood in full generality only by a few specialists.

Fairly expository articles on all of these conjectures can be found in the Park City lecture notes on the topic: "Arithmetic of L-functions", edited by Popescu, Rubin, and Silverberg, Volume 18 in the IAS/Park City mathematics series. Expository here means that the audience authors were supposed to have in mind is graduate students.

Kolster gives a lucid introduction to special values of zeta functions in particular in the introduction to

http://users.ictp.it/~pub_off/lectures/lns015/Kolster/Kolster_Final.pdf

If you are willing to to a lot of mental filing of "okay, there's some mathematical object called a 'thingy'", that introduction can give you a quick feel for the modern depth of the subject.

If you are willing to settle for learning classical knowledge of special values of L-functions, there are lots of good sources. A particularly nice, elementary discussion of Euler's original computation of zeta(2) is in William Dunham's excellent book, "Journey Through Genius".

Comment: Thank you.. I do not know what more to ask but thank you for your interest in responding to my question :)

Comment: You could also read my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1771242/30

Comment: see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/245a-supplement-1-a-little-bit-of-algebraic-number-theory-optional/#more-7863 for $L(1,\chi)$