# Explicit formular for special value of Dedekind zeta functions

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there any formula for $\zeta_{F}(1-k)$ where $F$ is real quadratic field and $k$ is positive even integers? Here $\zeta_{F}(s)$ is a Dedekind zeta function over a number field $F$.

Comment: see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84812/values-of-dirichlet-l-funcions-at-natural-numbers

Comment: @user8268 Thank you very much!

Comment: The  expression of the special values in terms of Bernoulli numbers is obtained by analytical means, but the "mystery" remains in the significance  of those *rational* numbers (as opposed to the transcendental nature of the zeta function). See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1771242/300700