# What is the importance of RH for $L$-functions of modular forms?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

The Reimann Hypothesis (RH) for $L$-functions of modular forms states that all the non-trivial zeroes of an $L$-function of a modular form must lie on the critical line. **My question is:** why is this conjecture important? What concrete consequences would it have?

In terms of what I'm looking for: I'm clear about the consequences of the Reimann hypothesis for the *ordinary* Reimann zeta function. RH for the ordinary zeta function is is important because it tells us about the distribution of prime numbers and gives us an improved error term for the Prime Number Theorem.

But does the Reimann Hypothesis for modular forms give us any similarly concrete information? Or is it more of a standalone statement about $L$-functions that doesn't "mean" anything per se?

In my mind, I don't know  why the location of the zeroes for $L$-functions of modular forms is important. All I know is that the "action" happens near $s=1$ because BSD links the behavior of the $L$-function to ranks of elliptic curves (at least for modular forms of weight $2$). I'm not sure, however, what meaning is attached to the zeroes of $L$-functions of modular forms *in general* (that is, *away* from $s=1$). Can we ascribe some meaning to the zeroes of these $L$-functions away from the point $s=1$ that makes RH important in this case?

Comment: Sorry, not "Reimann". For consequences of GRH see for example the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764582/significance-of-the-riemann-hypothesis-to-algebraic-number-theory).

Comment: If $K$ is an imaginary quadratic number field then $\zeta_K(s)$ is the L-function of a modular form and its RH has a similar meaning to that for $\zeta(s)$, replacing the primes by the prime ideals of $O_K$. The RH for the versions twisted by a (finite order) Hecke character will be analogous to the RH for Dirichlet L-functions (distributions of prime ideals in some kind of ideal class). To generalize you'll need to construct some Galois representation associated to the modular form.

Comment: Beside's Dietrich's link, see also this MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/q/17209/6518

Comment: I think these comments are just strengthening the question. There seem to be lists and lists of applications of the RH for the Riemann zeta function and more generally for Dirichlet $L$-functions. But the question is specifically about the RH for higher degree $L$-functions.